# How to make Grafana panel with just colour and text as link?

Tags: grafana

I want to make a simple panel with just:

- Text as a link to another dashboard
- Background as traffic light colour based on a metric
- Hidden underlying metric (do not want to see it)

Singlestat would be ideal but I can't see how to hide the metric or make text a link. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution:

- Use the SVG plugin (https://grafana.com/plugins/marcuscalidus-svg-panel)
- Create an SVG rectangle with the text you want (eg. Google drawing & export)
- Include a link in the SVG code (https://alligator.io/svg/hyperlinks-svg/)
- Change rectangle colour based on metrics (code inside the Javascript area):

To find the metrics to add to javascript:

- Use console.log(ctrl) to see what metrics are in your panel
- The one I wanted was in ctrl.series[0].stats.current

..............................................................................

My javascript code:

var S = Snap(svgnode);

var c = S.select("#rect");

if (ctrl.series[0].stats.current > 10)

```
c.attr({"fill": "#DAF7A6"});
```

..............................................................................

Good website for an example.
https://community.hiveeyes.org/t/how-to-visualize-2-dimensional-temperature-data-in-grafana/974/6
Youtube video with something similar:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aVS13Q36D34